# What does it mean by "Brownian motion is not the distribution function of any signed measure"?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Could someone explain me what does it mean by "Brownian motion is not the distribution function of any signed measure"? I was reading some notes on Stochastic calculus where I encountered this statement which is not vert clear to me,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any distribution function is almost everywhere differentiable, because it is monotone. Brownian motion is nowhere differentiable, so it cannot be a distribution function of any signed-measure.

Answer (score 1):

A real function $W$ is the distribution of a signed measure $m$ if the measure of $(a,b]$ equals $W(b)-W(a)$ for every real numbers $a<b$.

If $W$ is random and given by a Brownian motion, it is a continuous function and you could wonder whether this random function defines a random signed measure $m$. The statement quoted in the question is saying it (almost surely) does not.

One way to show that there is (a.s.) no signed measure whose distribution is given by $W$ is the following. Distribution functions of signed measures must have bounded variation, and the Brownian motion a.s. does not.